# Photoshohp 2019 Merge to HDR - Manual Set EV?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How does one manually set EV in creating a Photoshop HDR? (32bit)

I've searched and also [read the manual multiple times](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/high-dynamic-range-images.html) but can't seem to figure out how to manually set EV in the Photoshop 2019 Merge to HDR feature.

> If images lack exposure metadata, enter values in the Manually Set EV dialog box.

Where is the Set EV dialog box? Or how does one access this?

Comment: what do you see when you open Tools > Photoshop > Merge To HDR Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Manual Set EV dialog will only appear if there is no EXIF metadata on the images, otherwise Photoshop will read EXIF data, work out the EV settings automatically, and apply those.

So to get it to show up you'd need to strip the metadata from each image. This can be done using *Export > Save for Web(legacy), where you can set Metadata to "none". If you do this for each image you can then load those using Merge to HDR Pro, and the Manual Set EV dialog will appear.